# Eclipse cannot find class in jar if my src is not in default package

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

As above figure, when I define my src in the default package, Eclipse can find the class correctly. However, if I move the same src to package week1, Eclipse cannot resolves this class type anymore.

The source is fine, I can compile it in cmd line. I just try to figure out what really happened here in Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: When you move the source, do you also change the package name in the source file to week1?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö  I add 'package week1;' in the first line. Besides cannot find the class in the jar. the rest part of the source file,  because I can compile the code if I do not use the code from jar.